# Use Perl to extract certificates from a file

Tags: regex, perl, variables, certificate

Below is a text file, I would like to use Regex to take save the certificate which begins after

> "crossCertificatePair;binary::"

which symbolizes the beginning of a new cert, and run all the way to the end.  Each file has multiple certificates 
beginning the same way, and I would like a way to extract and save each one to a variable.

```
># extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
># base <cn=Federal Bridge CA,ou=FPKI,o=U.S. Government,c=US> with scope subtree
># filter: (objectclass=*)
># requesting: crossCertificatePair
>#

># Federal Bridge CA, FPKI, U.S. Government, US
dn: cn=Federal Bridge CA,ou=FPKI,o=U.S. Government,c=US
crossCertificatePair;binary:: MIINq6CCB2IwggdeMIIGRqADAgECAhAEBsw2n1386M2IP4F9
 Y9f9MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMGQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRUwEwYDVQQKEwxEaWdpQ2VydCBJbmMxG
 TAXBgNVBAsTEHd3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20xIzAhBgNVBAMTGkRpZ2lDZXJ0IEZlZGVyYXRlZCBJRC
 BDQS0xMB4XDTExMTIwNzEyMDAwMFoXDTE0MTIwNzEyMDAwMFowUjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxGDAWBgN
 VBAoTD1UuUy4gR292ZXJubWVudDENMAsGA1UECxMERlBLSTEaMBgGA1UEAxMRRmVkZXJhbCBCcmlk
 Z2UgQ0EwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC5M26e4VUSlib2braFWKYhaUs3Q
 SR9JwuQQHZQTmuhTOQScPO7g/JAdNvTFymOIHnXrinkPmOG+YyqxQQemNdIq3yi5AAUt+I6VOhsfS
 NhZTZJsSKoNsZ72TxqOVkLMvKWNyZxvcZK3bG1wx5eErtKqlRMjTovxGXwVktB4/J+iu975SIxT1m
 IaNsNWtyQOUF3T4P7K8/u1VwPmZ2SjMNYjKnFQU7E0Vfo1OEGWUrR0KrSBUT2Vu6PSj2OwkGr5ep6
 rr+2vjboHpWG64qOoBQHyGwd7u6f/2TPkoD5OOqGdKOD4byifwi4L5arausnxY+Yy7jMM+ifG1qKD
 GgupMJjAgMBAAGjggQcMIIEGDAPBgNVHRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBhjB8BggrBg
 EFBQcBAQRwMG4wJAYIKwYBBQUHMAGGGGh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbTBGBggrBgEFBQc
 wAoY6aHR0cDovL2NhY2VydHMuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL2FpYURpZ2lDZXJ0RmVkZXJhdGVkSURDQS0x
 LnA3YzCBgQYDVR0fBHoweDA6oDigNoY0aHR0cDovL2NybDMuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL0RpZ2lDZXJ0R
 mVkZXJhdGVkSURDQS0xLmNybDA6oDigNoY0aHR0cDovL2NybDQuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL0RpZ2lDZX
 J0RmVkZXJhdGVkSURDQS0xLmNybDCBowYDVR0gBIGbMIGYMAwGCmCGSAGG/WwEAQEwDAYKYIZIAYb
 9bAQBAjALBglghkgBhv1sBAIwDAYKYIZIAYb9bAQDATAMBgpghkgBhv1sBAMCMAwGCmCGSAGG/WwE
 BAEwDAYKYIZIAYb9bAQEAjAMBgpghkgBhv1sBAUBMAwGCmCGSAGG/WwEBQIwDAYKYIZIAYb9bAQFA
 zALBglghkgBhv1sAQswggEpBgNVHSEEggEgMIIBHDAYBgpghkgBhv1sBAEBBgpghkgBZQMCAQMBMB
 gGCmCGSAGG/WwEAQIGCmCGSAFlAwIBAwEwFwYJYIZIAYb9bAQCBgpghkgBZQMCAQMCMBgGCmCGSAG
 G/WwEAwEGCmCGSAFlAwIBAwMwGAYKYIZIAYb9bAQDAgYKYIZIAWUDAgEDDjAYBgpghkgBhv1sBAQB
 BgpghkgBZQMCAQMMMBgGCmCGSAGG/WwEBAIGCmCGSAFlAwIBAw8wGAYKYIZIAYb9bAQFAQYKYIZIA
 WUDAgEDEjAYBgpghkgBhv1sBAUCBgpghkgBZQMCAQMTMBgGCmCGSAGG/WwEBQMGCmCGSAFlAwIBAx
 QwFwYJYIZIAYb9bAELBgpghkgBZQMCAQMIMIHfBggrBgEFBQcBCwSB0jCBzzA/BggrBgEFBQcwBYY
 zaHR0cDovL2h0dHAuZnBraS5nb3YvYnJpZGdlL2NhQ2VydHNJc3N1ZWRCeWZiY2EucDdjMIGLBggr
 BgEFBQcwBYZ/bGRhcDovL2xkYXAuZnBraS5nb3YvY249RmVkZXJhbCUyMEJyaWRnZSUyMENBLG91P
 UZQS0ksbz1VLlMuJTIwR292ZXJubWVudCxjPVVTP2NBQ2VydGlmaWNhdGU7YmluYXJ5LGNyb3NzQ2
 VydGlmaWNhdGVQYWlyO2JpbmFyeTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUxJ38nV06XQV6vwKB7NtJcBXHsnIwHwYDVR0
 jBBgwFoAU0Cs7/2hx1pAM98RzeceZcADlR0AwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAKDvyX5eyrDFTt6b
 trs0yB05nbjyeuF7ldfHoFWHhBYdLsKzmR5YdiTMDUBAGCGc7hpANkp1qLI2vjKlLPT9SU/OVa91m
 p9vH5YlxEqx5DtxhhWDxxhu1h1zcSanCJ89IMyiLvzJgQo9wrwcKbiFlfo02J/qPf3L8AHw3NAqCU
 MeSCL6dt/zIBlkKsaaGhVt8Rk5qnV92uTsNNlQ6t7Wb5Kb2hF6uB7/YAR2TzM6vLNKHIZPzc5vp0q
 MqlUvEliPCBfEcfEVCq4vMFHYsfP5bGuEu7lzWPkfKf5GEBu8W5z1URUeBS/oFY4W48CSit34JnKO
 piydiZ+jsEBRoXLZOZmhggZBMIIGPTCCBSWgAwIBAgICCDkwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwUjELMAkGA
 1UEBhMCVVMxGDAWBgNVBAoTD1UuUy4gR292ZXJubWVudDENMAsGA1UECxMERlBLSTEaMBgGA1UEAx
 MRRmVkZXJhbCBCcmlkZ2UgQ0EwHhcNMTIwMjA5MTUxNTQzWhcNMTQxMDI2MTQxMjIxWjBkMQswCQY
 DVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29t
 MSMwIQYDVQQDExpEaWdpQ2VydCBGZWRlcmF0ZWQgSUQgQ0EtMTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADg
 gEPADCCAQoCggEBAMJ4XArNzTmP4QFtzBT1MxQnTsOuyl/U6suW+5PA9BxpUEed1283vK/HatTaZ9
 WrYSM6p6h0iJF3Wc2E6LUVuHq9EfB5mYSXUadDHjkQOKmQZiZ6K2nt6ZwPFM0maD/DL7qD4ALeve3 ENxKR9/pdvewNWLLl4UWehkg8lJNuMOJ/6bLm54TNxooVzrg4mJbCVHYEqnvRZMWWTfuAisiRm9AJ
 A3E0Wb8h4tylCCYks/BddhHpa+MjZNuJ79KpxCKKPvOD6ZJ5Rz/qLESLngv5RKZ3EhlepbXh5xD3d
 +gTFW3vHdrhAK3FjhfO60U5sv/1POGpqLsaFTLwwHz76rtM0A4zygKNgf3X45tOyhI+mzaj9fM37M
 eWU=
crossCertificatePair;binary::MIIOIaCCBykwggclMIIGDaADAgECAhA1NaRHZsnFhU4oae9B
 MGFBMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMDYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRAwDgYDVQQKEwdPUkMgUEtJMRUwEwYDV.....etc
```

Answer (score 3):

While it can be solved with lookaround, I don't think it's a task for regexes:

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!;
my $binary = do { local $/ = undef; <$fh>; };
close $fh;

my @certs = split /\ncrossCertificatePair;binary::/, $binary;
shift @certs; # you don't need the first part
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question, then I guess you'll need to use the [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `?=` to allow you to match overlapping things.

This would do it:

```
open my $fh, "<", $filename or die $!;
{local $/; $content = <$fh>;}
close $fh;
my $content =~ s/\s+//g;
my @certs = ($content =~ /crossCertificatePair;binary::(.*?)(?=$|crossCertificatePair;binary::)/g);
```

Though it does make a few major assumptions, namely that a) you want to lose the spaces and newlines (if not, get rid of the fourth line), and b) that once you've started reading certificates, the only thing that can come next is another certificate or the end of the file.

Hopefully it's enough to get you going though.